# Link Websocket Connection to Logged in Users in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-security, websocket

**Server Side :**
I have a webSocket configuration ready like this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "gestionprojet.java")
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/notification");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/stomp").withSockJS();
  }

  protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
      messages
              .simpDestMatchers("/user/*").authenticated() ;
  }
}
```

And I have A spring Security Configuration Ready also and working with a custom UserDetailsInterface with DataBase integration for user management :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

  http.csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login", "/logout").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());

}

@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {

    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
}
```

}

And As you can see I've already implemented a 'sessionRegistery' so I can get the logged in users.

**On the client Side :**

```
    var startListener = function() {
    socket.stomp.subscribe(service.NOTIFICATION_TOPIC, function(data) {
        listener.notify(getMessage(data.body));
    });
};

var initialize = function() {
    socket.client = new SockJS(service.SOCKET_URL);
    socket.stomp = Stomp.over(socket.client);
    socket.stomp.connect({}, startListener);
    socket.stomp.onclose = reconnect;
};

initialize();
return service;
```

**My problem is :** I want to link the WebSocket connection to their respective Logged in users (sessions) so I can then send delever message to a specific user through websocket with :

```
webSocketMessageTemplate.convertAndSend("/notification/message", new WebSocketMessage(n));
```

Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you.